# Is there a dataset for the spatial extents of historic levels of the Great Lakes since the Last Glacial Maximum?

Tags: data, hydrography, north-america

Is there a dataset for the spatial extents of historic levels of the Great Lakes since the Last Glacial Maximum? More specifically, we are looking for the maximum level of the Great Lakes after 5,000 years before present.

I'm collaborating on some research on distribution of an aquatic species in the Great Lakes area. I am trying to see if the current distribution can be explained by the historic water levels of the Great Lakes.

I thought I would check to see if anyone is aware of such a dataset before I look into creating something myself.